# Connecting ADO.Net entity data model to database

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, xaml, datagrid

I have a WPF application using an ADO.NET entity data model. After creating the `edmx`, a connection string is by default created in `app.config` like this:

```
<add name="Entities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.DataAccess.DataModel.csdl|res://*/Model.DataAccess.DataModel.ssdl|res://*/Model.DataAccess.DataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=servername;initial catalog=databasename;integrated security=True;user id=username;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I use the entities in the code behind as follows:

```
Entities ent = new Entities();
var tes = (from e in ent.testtable
select e.name).tolist();
```

After I released the application, the users are not able to connect to the database. They get the error

> The underlying provider failed on Open.

The users does not have access to the database, however since the credentials in the config file has the access, shouldn't the users be able to access the database.

Please let me know if I am missing something here, as I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have **both** the `Integrated Security=True` as well as `User id=username;` in your "provider connection string".

Don't do this!

If you do, the `Integrated Security=true` will have precedence, so right now, the connection is attempted with the currently logged in user credentials.

You need to **remove** the `Integrated Security=true` from your provider connection string!

```
provider connection string=&quot;data source=servername;initial catalog=databasename;integrated security=True;user id=username;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;
                                                                                     ************************  <--- remove this part
```

Use this connection string instead:

```
<add name="Entities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.DataAccess.DataModel.csdl|res://*/Model.DataAccess.DataModel.ssdl|res://*/Model.DataAccess.DataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=servername;initial catalog=databasename;user id=username;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: I added the connection string as follows:<add name="Entities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.DataAccess.DataModel.csdl|res://*/Model.DataAccess.DataModel.ssdl|res://*/Model.DataAccess.DataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=servername;initial catalog=databasename;persist security info=True;user id=username;password=password;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
However, i get the error that the under lying connection failed to open.

Comment: I guess I got the reason, when I give user id password, it will tak e SqL authentication where as DB requires Windows Authentication